# Há necessidade do ".this" em um projeto Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Eu estou reescrevendo um aplicativo que originalmente foi escrito em Java no Android Studio. Agora estou reescrevendo em C# para o Xamarin Android, portanto uma dúvida me surgiu, em diversas classes eu me deparei com o código java tipo esse:

```
private void obterWidgets()
        {
            ibtAdicionar = (ImageButton)findViewById(Resource.Id.layout_listview_ibt_adicionar);
            ibtAdicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Bundle parametros = new Bundle();
                parametros.putInt("RegNumPedido", pedido.getRegNumPedido());
                startActivity(new Intent(PedidoItensGradeActivity.this, MercadoriasGradeActivity.class).putExtras(parametros));
            }
});
        lvItens = (ListView) findViewById(Resource.Id.layout_listview_lv_dados);
tvEmpty = (TextView) findViewById(Resource.Id.layout_listview_tv_empty);
tvEmpty.setText("Nenhum item encontrado");
    }
```

Que em C# fica dessa forma:

```
private void obterWidgets()
 {
            ibtAdicionar = (ImageButton)findViewById(Resource.Id.layout_listview_ibt_adicionar);
            ibtAdicionar.OnClickListener = new OnClickListenerAnonymousInnerClass(this);
        lvItens = (ListView) findViewById(Resource.Id.layout_listview_lv_dados);
tvEmpty = (TextView) findViewById(Resource.Id.layout_listview_tv_empty);
tvEmpty.Text = "Nenhum item encontrado";
 }

    private class OnClickListenerAnonymousInnerClass : View.OnClickListener
    {
        private readonly MissingClass outerInstance;

        public OnClickListenerAnonymousInnerClass(MissingClass outerInstance)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
        }

        public override void onClick(View v)
        {
            Bundle parametros = new Bundle();
            parametros.putInt("RegNumPedido", pedido.RegNumPedido);
            startActivity((new Intent(PedidoItensGradeActivity.this, typeof(MercadoriasGradeActivity))).putExtras(parametros));
        }
    }
```

Se vocês notarem no código em C# teremos a anti penultima linha:

```
startActivity((new Intent(PedidoItensGradeActivity.this, typeof(MercadoriasGradeActivity))).putExtras(parametros));
```

Com esse .this após o PedidoItensGradActivity ocasiona um erro, portanto se eu removo o .this o erro desaparece, portanto queria saber, há algo que substitua esse .this ou não há necessidade de tê-lo em meu código? Estou perguntando porque o aplicativo ainda não esta pronto para ser compilado!

Comment: O que é `PedidoItensGradeActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é necessário usar o `.this` no final da classe. Ou você usa o nome da classe ou apenas o `this`. Abaixo segue um exemplo de como seria a forma correta de iniciar uma `Activity` passando "parâmetros" para a mesma.

```
var activity = new Intent(this, typeof(MercadoriasGradeActivity));
activity.PutExtra("RegNumPedido", pedido.RegNumPedido);
StartActivity(activity);
```

Na hora de buscar esse valor na `MercadoriasGradeActivity`, faça o seguinte:

```
string numPedido = Intent.GetStringExtra("RegNumPedido") ?? null;
```